# how to edit next line after matching pattern and append the line if doesn't exist

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, scripting

I am looking for changing a file content which is repeated twice with that replacement I want to add extra line to second content in the same file

**Example file**

```
User YOURNAME
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/YOURKEY

.
.
.
User YOURNAME
Installing
Installing
```

**Example Output after running script**

```
User adminuser
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

.
.
.
User adminuser
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Installing
Installing
```

I am able to change the `user` and `YOURKEY` with the below `sed` command

```
`sed- i s/"YOURNAME/adminuser"/g /root/.ssh/config`
`sed -i 's/YOURKEY/id_rsa/g' ff1`
```

But I'm unable to insert `IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa` in the next line.

**edited**

additional info `****User adminuser` is having space at the beginning of the line. These files are getting synced on daily bases, So cant remove `IdentityFile` line. After sync it will get replaced

**Final edit which works as required**

```
perl -i -ne 'next if /IdentityFile/; 
            s#YOURNAME#adminuser\n    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa#; 
            print' filename
```

Comment: additional info `****User adminuser` is having space at the beaning of the line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove all cases of `IdentityFile` and then add them again explicitly:

```
$ perl -i -ne 'next if /IdentityFile/; 
            s#YOURNAME#adminuser\nIdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa#; 
            print' file
$ cat file
User adminuser
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

.
.
.
User adminuser
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Installing
Installing
```

The `next if /IdentityFile/` skips any lines matching `IdentityFile`. The `s#YOURNAME#adminuser\nIdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa#` will replace any instance of `YOURNAME` with `adminuser`, a newline and the `IdentityFile` line. The final `print` prints all lines.

Comment: Thanks Terdon, I am getting the output as required, but its not saved and can we have `****`space at the starting of the `IdentityFile` line.

Comment: @Mongrel just use `-i`. Perl is where `sed` got that idea from anyway. See updated answer.I have no idea what you mean with `****` space. Are the `*` supposed to be `*` or spaces? What difference does that make?

Comment: @Mongrel you can use `\t` right after `\n`

Comment: @Rahul why would I? Oh, you think that's what the OP means by "`*****` space`? If so, why assume they want a tab and not spaces? In any case, this really should be clarified in the question itself. Thanks for the edit, by the way.

Comment: \t will give me 8 space and I am looking for 4 space only. Rahul you are right I can user \t for <tab>

Comment: @Mongrel no, `\t` will not give you 8 spaces, it will give you one `\t`. Whether or not that's what you want depends on what you're doing. Tabs and spaces look the same to humans but not to computers.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that your template is inconsistent: the first occurrence *has* an `IdentityFile` line, while the second does *not*.  You can make it consistent by first deleting the existing `IdentityFile` lines, and then by adding lines which you want.

To delete lines:

```
sed -i '/^IdentityFile /d' filename
```

To add lines, you can do this in `sed` by *matching* the `User` line, and *appending* a line, e.g.,

```
sed -e '/^User /'a'\
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa' filename
```

Comment: Thomas I tried adding below the User section but in that file there is one more User section above. if there is a way which can verify if `IdentityFile ` exist if not then add the line.

Comment: these files are getting synced on daily bases, So cant remove `IdentityFile ` line. After sync it will get replaced.